# Как реализовать взаимодействие клиента с объектами в Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, сервер, servlet

Есть простое web приложение, включающее в себя несколько сервлетов,
каждый из которых коннектится к базе данных, создает модель и отображает ее через jsp. Я бы хотел оптимизировать работу с базой данных путем работы с Java-объектами вместо таблиц.
К примеру, если нужно получить из таблицы автобусов автобус с определенным id,
то вместо коннекта базы данных получаем объект автобуса из хэш-таблицы, что сработает во много раз быстрее.

Реализовать я думал так: сохранить данные таблиц б.д. в объектах при первом коннекте, затем работать с этими объектами, а в случае изменения б.д. изменять объекты и таблицы.

Не знаю, как создать такой класс "база данных", который бы хранил все данные и при этом не удалялся из памяти при завершении работы сервлета. Хотел бы узнать, как это можно сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону ORM, может быть Вам подойдет именно оно.

Comment: а зачем вам нужно ускорение? вы померили нагрузку и поняли, что текущая архитектура не справляется?

Comment: Стандарт ORM продвигаемый JavaEE - JPA https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence. Наиболее известные представители: EclipseLink (образцово-показательная реализация), Hibernate. JPA входит в состав JavaEE Web Profile, поэтому должен быть доступен сразу "из коробки" в любом сервере приложений. Есть и противоборствующие конфеcсии, например JDO. Да и тот же Hibertate появился задолго до JPA и может работать и как JPA и по-своему. Все умеют использовать пул подключений, кешировать результаты запросов в несколько уровней, если так заботит производительность.

Answer (score 3):

Паттерн называется Data Access Object или просто DAO. 
Пишете такой класс, который инкапсулирует работу с БД внутри себя. Например BusDao, у которого есть метод byId который возвращает объект Bus. Так же можно написать кучу подобных методов (byName, byModel и т.п.)

Внутри BusDao можно хранить полученные данные в "самопальном" кеше на основе HashMap, например. Тут надо заморочиться с ключом, чтоб он был железно уникальным для каждого объекта.

Соответственно, чтобы данные "гуляли" от сервлета к сервлету наш DAO так же должен быть singleton-ом (тоже паттерн такой).

Вот собственно и все, никакой магии)

Но как заметили в комментарии, можно попробовать использовать какой-либо ORM (Hibernate, Ebean, [тысячи их](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_ORM-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA#Java)). В жизни пригодится, ибо нет проектов их не использующих при работе с БД.